# how to change mega menu hover to on click in small screen size?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can I change mega menu hover to on click?

```js
$(function() {
    $(".dropdown").hover(
        function() {
            $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop(true, true).fadeIn("slow");
            $(this).toggleClass('open');
        },
        function() {
            $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop(true, true).fadeOut("slow");
            $(this).toggleClass('open');
        });
});
```

I changed .hover to .click but It doesnt work.

Comment: Can you provide JSFIDDLE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replicate the hover off method. It is difficult to know for sure without having the DOM too but something like this should work.

```
$(function() {
  $(".dropdown").click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('open')) {
      $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop(true, true).fadeOut("slow");
      $(this).toggleClass('open');
    } else {
      $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop(true, true).fadeIn("slow");
      $(this).toggleClass('open');
    }
  });
});
```

Basically you need to check to see if the menu is open, and run the code that would normally fire when you un-hover if it is.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'd remove the `.stop()` methods in the chain. Other than that, without a working demo it's very difficult to know what is going wrong. Can you post a jsFiddle as an example?

Comment: the browser says Unexpected token ( i think there is something wrong with code can you check it?

Comment: Is it possible to make it hover In large screen size and on click in small?

Comment: It is, a few ways to do that. You can just add an if/else statement that used your old code if the screen size was larger than whatever size you wanted the switch to happen, and the new way if it was smaller than that.

Answer (score 0):

When clicked on dropdown class, if the current item is in hidden state then I am showing or opening the element using `fadeIn`. Else if it is already opened or not hidden then closing it using `fadeOut`.

Also in second block of code i am making sure that menu gets closed when you click anywhere outside the menu component.

```
$(function() {
  $(".dropdown").click(function() {
    if($(this).find(".dropdown-menu").is(":hidden")){
      //opening menu when it is not open already
      $(".dropdown-menu").hide();
      $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop(true, true).fadeIn("slow");
    }
    else{
      //closing menu when it is open already on same item click
      $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop(true, true).fadeOut("slow");

    }
  });
});
$('html').click(function() {
  //Hide the menus if visible when click outside menu
  $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop(true, true).fadeOut("slow");
});

$('.dropdown, .dropdown-menu').click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to SO, but please consider adding an explanation, besides only posting code.

Comment: When clicked on dropdown class, if the current item is in hidden state then I am showing or opening the element using fadeIn. else if it is already opened or not Hidden then closing it using fadeOut. Also in second block of code i am making sure that menu gets closed when you click anywhere outside the menu component. Hope it helps you :-)